# ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback onSwiped in nested RecyclerView with CardViews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, itemtouchhelper, nestedrecyclerview

In my app I have a (primary) RecyclerView that shows CardViews. In each CardView displayed there is in turn a (secondary) RecyclerView, which also displays CardViews. (Nested RecyclerView)
These (secondary) RecyclerViews are set up in the onBindViewHolder method in the adapter of the primary RecyclerView, where I also allow swiping the CardViews in the (secondary) RecyclerView using ItemTouchHelper.

```
public void onBindViewHolder( RkTageViewHolder holder, int position ) {
...
     LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager( holder.rvAbschnitte.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
     current.setRkAbschnitte(m_rkAbschnittDao.getRkAbschnittListe(current.getReiseID()));
     layoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(current.getRkAbschnitte().size());
     RkAbschnitteAdapter rkAbschnitteAdapter = new rkAbschnitteAdapter(current.getRkAbschnitte());
    holder.rvAbschnitte.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    holder.rvAbschnitte.setAdapter(rkAbschnitteAdapter);

...

    new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
      @Override
      public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
      }

      @Override
      public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        Toast.makeText(holder.rvAbschnitte.getContext(), "Löschen aktuell nicht möglich...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(holder.rvAbschnitte);

...

}
```

Everything works perfectly until I also allow swiping of the CardViews in the primary RecyclerView. No matter where I swipe, only the CardView is moved in the primary RecyclerView.

If I only allow swiping to the right in the primary RecyclerView and to swipe to the left in the secondary, it works. As soon as I allow swiping in the same direction in both RecyclerViews, only the cardViews in the primary RecyclerView are moved.

Is there a way to tell the primary RecyclerView that it will pass the swipe command on to its child RecyclerView when the swipe is carried out there?

Many thanks

Uwe